# finding whether the body contains gzipped data

Tags: c++, curl, gzip

i have a program wherein it searches the reply from a curl request for specific strings. i sometimes get gzipped data. is there a way to find whether the reply is text or gzipped format?
header sometimes contain gziipped,deflate header, but its not consistent. is there a way to search the string and find if its gzipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try taking a look at the first two bytes of data. For gzipped data, [they should be 0x1f, 0x8b](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer).

```
Member header and trailer

ID1 (IDentification 1)
ID2 (IDentification 2)
These have the fixed values ID1 = 31 (0x1f, \037), ID2 = 139 (0x8b, \213),
to identify the file as being in gzip format.
```

Comment: the reply is saved in a string. so how to proceed from there?

Comment: if (string[0] == 0x1f && string[1] == 0x8b) { blah blah blah;}

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but when i tried so, it didnot match. when i printed the string, it contained all illegible language or symbols but the first two letters where C and W.. so how do i proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the first bytes of the file. Perhaps they containt a [magic number](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html#Compressed).

Answer (score 0):

The gzip file format starts with some "magic bytes". You can check whether the body starts with these, and if it does, push back the bytes into the stream and start unzipping it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe it through zcat, and if it fails, use the string as is. Sloppy I know, but it ought to be reliable; a plain text file would never contain valid gzipped data.

Answer (score 0):

Standards-compliant HTTP responses will contain a Content-Encoding: or Transfer-Encoding: header specifying "gzip" for compressed responses, eliminating the need to guess by looking at magic number. Unfortunately, lots of sites get these headers wrong, though.